# JPQL NOT IN id list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have class A and class B.

```
class A {
    List<B> bs;
}

class B {
    Integer id;
}
```

I have to write JPQL query that will select all as, except that have B with some id;

I am trying to do the following:

```
@Query("FROM A a INNER JOIN a.bs b WHERE b NOT IN (FROM B WHERE id = :bId)")
```

or

```
@Query("FROM A a INNER JOIN a.bs b WITH b.id != :bId")
```

But that doesn't work for me.

Comment: JPQL starts with "SELECT a".

Comment: You should look at "b NOT MEMBER OF ..."

Comment: @NeilStockton that doesn't needed if you want to select whole object

Comment: @Query("Select a FROM A a INNER JOIN a.bs b WHERE b.id <> :bId")

Comment: Yes it is needed if you want to COMPLY WITH THE JPA SPEC. Omit that and your queries are NON-PORTABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT a FROM A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT b FROM a.bs b WHERE b.id=:bId)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```html
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE ((SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.id=:param) NOT MEMBER OF a.bs OR (SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.id=:param)IS NULL)
```

this is a very simple way of solving your problem. Actualy, we select all elements in A where (here we look for b with the id "param" and we make sure that the element found is not in a.bs ) the "OR" here is also important because when there is no b with the id, the element in A must be selected and the first part of the or is not enough for that.